# histograms in python with decimal

Tags: python, decimal, histogram

I have several lists of Decimal python types and I need a code to plot the normalized distribution of these.

When I use code from previous posts, it seems that matplotlib does not support these kind of plots for decimals.

Can someone show me an alternative, please?

Comment: Make a temp numpy array of your decimal values converted to numpy float for the plotting

Answer (score 4):

Use `np.asarray(data, dtype='float')` to convert your list of `Decimals` into a NumPy array of floats:

```
import numpy as np
import decimal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
D = decimal.Decimal
N = 100
data = [D(str(item)) for item in np.random.random(N)]
plt.hist(np.asarray(data, dtype='float'), bins=10, normed=True)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]